# how to select XElement element and its child in a single Linq Query

Tags: linq-to-xml

I need to select the parent and child in a single step so that i can get them as IEnumerable and iterate over them

I tried parent.descendantsandself but doesn't work any idea

```
<MenuItem id="MyAccount" rmId="MyAccount" loc-attr="MyAccount,text" text="My Account" target="" display="true">
  <MenuItem id="MyProducts" rmId="MyProducts" loc-attr="MyProducts,text" text="My McAfee Products" target="" display="true" href="http://home.mcafee.com/root/myAccount.aspx" />
  <MenuItem id="MyProfile" rmId="MyProfile" loc-attr="MyProfile,text" text="Update McAfee Account Info" target="" display="true" href="https://home.mcafee.com/Secure/Protected/MyAccountInfo.aspx" />
  <MenuItem id="MyArSettings" rmId="MyArSettings" loc-attr="MyArSettings,text" text="My Auto-Renewal Settings" href="https://home.mcafee.com/Secure/Protected/AutoRenew.aspx" target="" display="true" />
</MenuItem>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the information you have provided I think `DescendantsAndSelf` should work, for instance when I try

```
            XElement item = XElement.Parse(@"<MenuItem Id=""m1"">
  <MenuItem Id=""m2""></MenuItem>
  <MenuItem Id=""m3""></MenuItem>
</MenuItem>");
            foreach (XElement menu in item.DescendantsAndSelf())
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}", menu.Attribute("Id").Value);
            }
```

it nicely outputs the id of all three elements:

```
m1
m2
m3
```

If you still have problems with code not doing what you want it to do then consider to show us enough of that code to allow us reproduce the problem.